# Excel.Workbooks.Open fails with HRESULT: 0x800A03EC in development environment

Tags: c#, excel-interop

Back in the day Excel Interop was a reliable tool.  Today it simply would not work.
I realize that the HRESULT is extremely generic and provides very little context.  I have examined the other questions which I will summarize:

1. The files were corrupt.
2. The files used a non-US English locale.
3. It worked fine in the development environment, but it failed in a
   server environment.

None of these apply. The file is not corrupt.  It opens fine in Excel.  It uses US English locale. It doesn't work even in the development environment.  We have recently changed to use Office 365 ProPlus, but I've found documentation that says the current interop should work with Office 365.  I'm using version 15.0.0.0 of the interop DLL with this code. I'm running Windows 10.0.17134 and Visual Studio 2017 Pro Version 15.8.8.  The app is a console app targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace DERPA_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            string templateFilename = "template.xlsx";

            if (File.Exists(templateFilename))
            {
                try
                {
                    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                    object misValue = Missing.Value;
                    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(templateFilename);
                    // Exception thrown here in the Open.
                    // Also tried this.  It didn't work either.
                    // xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(templateFilename, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                    xlApp.Quit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an even simpler example.  Create a CSV file named "test.csv" and containing:

> "Header 1","Header2"
>   "Data 1","Data 2"

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace DERPA_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("test.csv");
        }
    }
}
```

This has the same behavior.

Comment: I realize you stated that file is not corrupt, but humor me and try: `xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename: templateFilename, CorruptLoad: Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile);`.  You will also need to alter the close statement: `xlWorkBook.Close(SaveChanges: true, Filename: templateFilename);`

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and made sure the values are properly being filled?

Comment: Yes I have tried using repair file.  It made no difference.

Comment: Yes I have stepped through.  The file exists test succeeds. The Excel.Application returns a COM object with the correct name (Excel.Application).  Then the open throws an exception.  It never gets to the close.  I've tried opening a CSV file with two rows and two columns.  It does the same thing.

Comment: probably it is a permission problem. i can't remember details of excel interop, but i suppose it runs an excel.exe in background, and it may be that the excel.exe process 'today' runs under different permissions than 'yesterday'

Comment: You need to specify full path of excel file You work on : C:/Desktop/Test.xlsx